# libodbc.2dylib on apple silicon

Tags: apple-m1

Anyone tried to using sqlcmd on M1 Mac? When I try to use one I get an error :

> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libodbc.2.dylib
> Referenced from: /opt/homebrew/bin/sqlcmd
> Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
> /usr/local/lib/libodbc.2.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
> /usr/local/lib/libodbc.2.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
> /usr/local/lib/libodbc.2.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
> /usr/local/lib/libodbc.2.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
> [1]    99072 abort      sqlcmd

Anyone have a similar issue? Know any workarounds or something?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It's hard to answer without enough background to be reproducible. In this case: How did you install `libodbc`? And what's the output of `arch` on your terminal prior to `sqlcmd`?